# SQL stored procedures with many joins VS many database calls to simple stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a general question regarding database performance. I am using DotNetNuke business logic to create business objects and SQL 2008 R2. It's a web application (asp.net/c#).

Consider the following:

I need to load a userprofile that contains alot of information like name, lastname, XP, coins, won, lost, etc etc. Alot of fields from 10 different tables.

I have created one big stored procedure that contains many joins (and nested select/count statements) to get all this information in one database call.

My question is this, is this the correct approach? Or is it better/more performant to make many small database calls to simple stored procedures?

My idea was that it's better to make one databasecall, specially if you start having hundreds of thousands of users. But the joins are starting to be complex and its starting to take some time to load the profile.

Any thoughts? Or ideas?

Comment: I'd say its probably a safe assumption that the single query is going to perform better in most cases, assuming also of course that the tables are properly indexed and the sql itself is optimized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say, in general, that a single stored procedure is going to lead to a faster page load time than multiple stored procedures. For most stored procedures that are used within simple web applications, the query execution time is much smaller than the wire time. In other words, in my experience, just the act of going to the DB and back to the web server takes more time than executing the query.

However, here are a few things to consider.

1. Do you need to join to every table for every query execution? Or, are some joins only necessary based on the presence of data in other tables? If some joins are optional, you may want to consider pushing them into a separate stored procedure that is called only when needed.
2. While a single stored procedure might be faster, the complexity of the procedure might also lead to a much harder to maintain system. That complexity could spill out over from the database layer and into the application layer too. Consider trying to populate an Order object from a data result set. If you are optimizing for query time, you could imagine  pulling the data necessary to populate the order object in different ways from several different stored procedures. That could seriously complicate object creation. Is the gain in performance worth the  maintainability hit?
3. If you have additional concerns, it's always best to run a SQL profile. You can compare and contrast the CPU and IO for both the single complicated proc against calling several, smaller procs.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean in argument #2, it looks mixed

Answer (score 1):

If you really need all that data at the same time, I'd go for the SP. If it's slow you can tune it.

If you only need a little bit of that data most of the time, and some of it only now and then I'd go for less complex SPs, but more of them, but only called when needed.